# Send Welcome Message on Twitter via API

Tags: php, curl, twitter

Twitter introduced a new endpoint `direct_messages/events/new`  for sending welcome message to users and this will replace the `direct_messages/new` endpoint by `June 19, 2018`.

I developed an app http://tweeasy.com that uses `direct_messages/new` endpoint to sends direct messages to new followers of the authenticated user of the app.
Due to this change, I want o to implement new endpoint in my app but I didn't find this method in any available library of PHP. I am currently using codebird library.

Is there anyway to implement this new method in Codebird or any other library.

It will also work if I can implement this using Curl.

I tried this code but its giving below error

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

Here is my code

```
$apiUrl="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/new.json";

$methodType="POST";

//Auth Parameters

$consumerKey=$appToken['consumer_key']; //app_key
$consumerSecret=$appToken['consumer_secret']; // app_secret
$noucne= substr(md5(microtime(true)),0,8);
$signature="";
$signatureMethod="HMAC-SHA1";
$timestamp=time();
$userOauth=$userToken[0]['oauth_token'];
$userSecret=$userToken[0]['oauth_token_secret'];

//API PARAMS / Header
$params=array(
"oauth_consumer_key"=>$consumerKey,
"oauth_nonce"=>$noucne,
"oauth_signature_method"=>$signatureMethod,
"oauth_timestamp"=>$timestamp,
"oauth_version"=>1.0,
    "oauth_token"=>$userOauth
    );


// BUILD SIGNATURE
```

The `oauth_signature` thing I am finding hard know if its correct or not.
I used code from stackoverflow for generating signature.

```
// BUILD URL
// Resort
uksort($params, 'strcmp');
// convert params to string
foreach ($params as $k => $v) {$urlPairs[] = $k."=".$v;}
$concatenatedUrlParams = implode('&', $urlPairs);
// form url
$url = $apiBaseUrl.$url."?".$concatenatedUrlParams;

//initialize curl
$curlObj = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
//curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);


$response = curl_exec($curlObj);

// Change the response json string to object
//$jsonResult = json_decode($response);


$httpStatus=curl_getinfo($curlObj,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

echo $httpStatus;

curl_close($curlObj);
```

Comment: Why not make a pull request to one of the PHP libraries you talked about?

Comment: @FrankerZ . Yes I tried to do that but didn't success to add new method into existing library

Comment: I have a new library we can add this to if you'd like to work with me on it.  Check my profile here for contact info.

Comment: Currently I am able to send DM using Abraham's TwitterOAuth library with another branch https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/tree/json-post.